# Editing MySQL row via POST form

Tags: php, mysql, post

I've encountered a problem which i'll try to describe below...

Let's say i've got a button for each table row (table is created by acquiring the data from the database...). the button sends a massive of values via post.

```
<button value='$e->eventId|$e->eventType|$e->eventDate|$e->eventPrice|$e->eventDescr' name='editValue'>EDIT</button>
```

I've written a function to explode the values of the massive and fill the inputs on the same page.

```
if(!empty($_POST['editValue'])) {
    $editValue_fill = explode("|", $_POST["editValue"]);
    $eventId = $editValue_fill[0];
    $eventType = $editValue_fill[1];
    $eventDate = $editValue_fill[2];
    $eventPrice = $editValue_fill[3];
    $eventDescr = $editValue_fill[4];
}
```

Next comes the function to edit the row in the database.

```
function editEvent ($id, $type, $date, $price, $descr){

    $mysqli = new mysqli($GLOBALS["serverHost"], $GLOBALS["serverUsername"], $GLOBALS['serverPassword'], $GLOBALS['dbName']);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE events_archive SET eventType='?', eventDate='?', eventPrice='?', eventDescr='?' WHERE id='?'");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssdss", $type, $date, $price, $descr, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    header("Refresh:0");

    if($stmt->execute()){
        $eventNotice="Event successfully updated!";
    }else{
        $eventNotice = "Failed to save...";
    }
    return $eventNotice;
}
```

And, of course, the usage of the function which apparently doesnt work. The page just refreshes and nothing happens.

```
if(empty($eventTypeError)&& empty($eventDateError)&& empty($eventPriceError) && empty($eventDescrError)
    && isset($_POST['eventType']) && isset($_POST['eventDate']) && isset ($_POST['eventPrice']) && isset
    ($_POST['eventDescr']) && !empty($eventId)){
    $eventNotice = editEvent($eventId, cleanInput($eventType), cleanInput($eventDate), cleanInput($eventPrice), cleanInput($eventDescr));
}
```

So basically, gets values from the row -> fills them into inputs in the same page -> if $eventId is set then updates the row, if not - creates a new row (diff. function)

Could anyone give me a tip or help solving the problem? I've been trying to understand the issue and failed dramatically...

```
<?php
require ("functions.php");

var_dump($_POST);
//kas on sisseloginud, kui ei ole siis
//suunata login lehele

//kas ?logout on aadressireal
if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: login.php");
}

if (!isset ($_SESSION["userId"])){
    header("Location: login.php");
}
$confirm = "";
$eventNotice = "";
$eventTypeError = "";
$eventDateError = '';
$eventPriceError = '';
$eventDescrError = '';
$eventType = '';
$eventDescr = '';
$eventPrice = '';
$eventDate = date("Y-m-d");



if (isset ($_POST["eventType"])){
    if (empty($_POST['eventType'])){
        $eventTypeError = "Please choose the event type!";
    } else {
        $eventType = $_POST["eventType"];
    }
}

if (isset ($_POST ["eventDate"])){
    if (empty ($_POST ["eventDate"])){
        $eventDateError = "Please choose the date!";
    } else {
        $eventDate = $_POST["eventDate"];
    }
}

if (isset ($_POST ["eventPrice"])){
    if (empty ($_POST ["eventPrice"])){
        $eventPriceError = "Please type in the price!";
    } else {
        $eventPrice = $_POST["eventPrice"];
    }
}

if (isset ($_POST ["eventDescr"])){
    if (empty ($_POST ["eventDescr"])){
        $eventDescrError = "Please type in the description!";
    }elseif (strlen($_POST["eventDescr"])< 10) {
        $eventDescrError = "Description must be longer than 10 symbols!";
        $eventDescr = $_POST['eventDescr'];
    }else{
        $eventDescr = $_POST['eventDescr'];
    }
}

$event = getAllEvents();

if(!empty($_POST['delValue'])) {
    delEvent($_POST['delValue']);
}

if(!empty($_POST['editValue'])) {
    $editValue_fill = explode("|", $_POST["editValue"]);
    $eventId = $editValue_fill[0];
    $eventType = $editValue_fill[1];
    $eventDate = $editValue_fill[2];
    $eventPrice = $editValue_fill[3];
    $eventDescr = $editValue_fill[4];
    echo ($eventId);
    echo ($eventDate);
    echo ($eventPrice);
    echo ($eventType);
    echo ($eventDescr);
}



if(empty($eventTypeError)&& empty($eventDateError)&& empty($eventPriceError) && empty($eventDescrError)
    && isset($_POST['eventType']) && isset($_POST['eventDate']) && isset ($_POST['eventPrice']) && isset
    ($_POST['eventDescr'])){
    if(isset($_POST['editValue'])){
        $eventNotice = editEvent($eventId, cleanInput($eventType), cleanInput($eventDate), cleanInput($eventPrice), cleanInput($eventDescr));
    }elseif(!isset($_POST['editValue'])){
        $eventNotice = newEvent(cleanInput($eventType), cleanInput($eventDate), cleanInput($eventPrice), cleanInput($eventDescr));
    }

}

?>


<html>

<style>
    @import "styles.css";
    ul.tab {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    ul.tab li {float: left;}
    ul.tab li a {
        display: inline-block;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: 0.3s;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    ul.tab li a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
    .tabcontent {
        display: none;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-top: none;
    }
</style>


<body>
<form method ="post">
    <table class="table1">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center"><h1>Data</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><h2>Profile</h2></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="table2">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"">Welcome <?=$_SESSION['email'];?>!</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center"><a href="?logout=1">Log out</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        <tr>
            <td>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <ul class="tab">
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Add/edit')" id="defaultOpen">Add/edit</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Archive')">Archive</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <div id="Add/edit" class="tabcontent">
                                <input type="hidden" value='eventId'>
                                <table class="table2">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Event type:<span class = 'redtext'>*</span></td>
                                        <td style="text-align:left">
                                            <select name="eventType">

                                                <?php if(empty($eventType)){?>
                                                    <option value="" selected>Choose here</option>
                                                <?php } else { ?>
                                                    <option value="">Choose here</option>
                                                <?php } ?>

                                                <?php if($eventType == "Planned service"){?>
                                                    <option value="Planned service" selected>Planned service</option>
                                                <?php } else { ?>
                                                    <option value="Planned service">Planned service</option>
                                                <?php } ?>

                                                <?php if($eventType == "Unplanned service"){?>
                                                    <option value="Unplanned service" selected>Unplanned service</option>
                                                <?php } else { ?>
                                                    <option value="Unplanned service">Unplanned service</option>
                                                <?php } ?>

                                                <?php if($eventType == "Fuel checks"){?>
                                                    <option value="Fuel checks" selected>Fuel checks</option>
                                                <?php } else { ?>
                                                    <option value="Fuel checks">Fuel checks</option>
                                                <?php } ?>

                                                <?php if($eventType == "Tuning"){?>
                                                    <option value="Tuning" selected>Tuning</option>
                                                <?php } else { ?>
                                                    <option value="Tuning">Tuning</option>
                                                <?php } ?>

                                                <?php if($eventType == "Car accident"){?>
                                                    <option value="Car accident" selected>Car accident</option>
                                                <?php } else { ?>
                                                    <option value="Car accident">Car accident</option>
                                                <?php } ?>

                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr><td colspan="3" class="redtext" style="text-align:center"><?=$eventTypeError?></td></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Date:<span class = 'redtext'>*</span></td>
                                        <td style="text-align:left"><input name="eventDate" type ="date" min="1900-01-01" max = "<?=date('Y-m-d'); ?>" value = "<?=$eventDate?>" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr><td colspan="3" class="redtext" style="text-align:center"><?=$eventDateError?></td></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Price:<span class = 'redtext'>*</span></td>
                                        <td style="text-align:left"><input type="text" name="eventPrice" placeholder="ex. 15.50" onkeypress="return onlyNumbersWithDot(event);" / value = "<?=$eventPrice?>"></td>

                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            function onlyNumbersWithDot(e) {
                                                var charCode;
                                                if (e.keyCode > 0) {
                                                    charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
                                                }
                                                else if (typeof (e.charCode) != "undefined") {
                                                    charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
                                                }
                                                if (charCode == 46)
                                                    return true
                                                if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                                                    return false;
                                                return true;
                                            }
                                        </script>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr><td colspan="3" class="redtext" style="text-align:center"><?=$eventPriceError?></td></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Description:<span class = 'redtext'>*</span></td>
                                        <td style="text-align:left"><textarea name="eventDescr" cols="50" rows="10" placeholder="Describe event here..."><?=$eventDescr?></textarea></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr><td colspan="3" class="redtext" style="text-align:center"><?=$eventDescrError?></td></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center"><button type ="submit" value = "Submit">Save</button></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center"><p class = "redtext"><?=$eventNotice;?></p></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
</form>
<form method="post">


    <div id="Archive" class="tabcontent">
        <table class="table2">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"">
                <?php
                $html = "<table>";
                $html .= "<tr>";
                $html .= "<th>Event type</th>";
                $html .= "<th>Date</th>";
                $html .= "<th>Price(€)</th>";
                $html .= "<th>Description</th>";
                $html .= "<th>Delete</th>";
                $html .= "<th>Edit</th>";
                $html .= "</tr>";

                foreach($event as $e){
                    $html .= "<tr>";
                    $html .= "<td>$e->eventType</td>";
                    $html .= "<td>$e->eventDate</td>";
                    $html .= "<td>$e->eventPrice</td>";
                    $html .= "<td>$e->eventDescr</td>";
                    $html .= "<td><button style='border:none; background-color: transparent;' value='$e->eventId' name='delValue' onclick=\"return confirm('Do you really want to delete this row?')\"><img src='delete.png' width='20' height='20'></button></td>";
                    $html .= "<td><button style='border:none; background-color: transparent;' value='$e->eventId|$e->eventType|$e->eventDate|$e->eventPrice|$e->eventDescr' name='editValue'><img src='edit.png' width='20' height='20'></button></td>";
                    $html .= "</tr>";
                }

                $html .= "</table>";
                echo $html;

                ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </div>
    <script>
        function openTab(evt, tabName) {
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        }

        // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
        document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    </script>
    </td>


    </tr>

    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </div>
</form>






</body>
</html>
```

Looking forward to Your help!
Best regards :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['editValue'])){
    $eventNotice = editEvent($eventId, cleanInput($eventType), cleanInput($eventDate), cleanInput($eventPrice), cleanInput($eventDescr));
}
```

Comment: Not really what im looking for... now the page just fills the inputs and submits them. Basically updates the values with the same values.

Comment: try echoing values used in if condition and check which condition is failing

Comment: Seems like submit just creates a new row with function, even though eventId is set... `if(empty($eventTypeError)&&
    empty($eventDateError)&& empty($eventPriceError) && empty($eventDescrError) && isset($_POST['eventType'])
    && isset($_POST['eventDate']) && isset ($_POST['eventPrice']) && isset ($_POST['eventDescr']) && !isset($_POST['editValue'])){
    $eventNotice = newEvent(cleanInput($eventType), cleanInput($eventDate), cleanInput($eventPrice), cleanInput($eventDescr));
}`

Comment: can you share your complete php snippet for post function

Comment: also the php code after submit. Also i do not see this button code which you mentioned.. <button value='$e->eventId|$e->eventType|$e->eventDate|$e->eventPrice|$e->eventDescr' name='editValue'>EDIT</button>

Comment: maybe i'll just show you the whole code?.. im quite confused right now

Comment: In button value, you are passing the values which you already get from database. to get the updated values from form, you should use $_POST['field name']

Comment: `array(1) { ["editValue"]=> string(56) "112|Unplanned service|2016-10-24|14.4|asdsadasdasdsdasda" }`

Comment: you are not passing any new values. You are just passing the values which you get from database.

Comment: I'm passing the values to fill the inputs. Maybe i'm not getting something? :/